# Azure Web App Authentication not protecting the root url

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have an Azure Web App where I have deployed a .Net 4.7 application with Umbraco CMS.

I want to require login before showing any content to a user.

Under the "Authentication" settings in the portal, I have configured an auth0 identity provider, and configured it as below:

[image]

Now, the issue is that it is not protecting the root url of the site. So:

```
GET https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net => HTTP 200

GET https://mywebapp.azurewebsites.net/foo => HTTP 302 (Redirect to auth0)
```

Why would the root url not get the same 302 redirect?

**Update**

I tried reproducing this with a basic dotnet 8 application deployed to Azure, and that had no problem redirecting the `/` url to the login page, so this must be either a .Net Framework or Umbraco specific thing.

I still wonder how any requests reach the underlying code when the authentication is enabled, but maybe it just extends the application through http modules?

Comment: Have you configured with the credentials in your app? Or only configured in Authentication in Azure App Service ?

Comment: @Harshitha the app knows nothing about authentication. It's only configured on the app service. And it's set to only allow authenticated traffic.

Comment: What is the Metadata URL you have added?

Comment: Refer this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5297820/Azure-Active-Directory-Authentication-with-OpenID) once